# iPhone iOS what is the correct way to do actions with UIView animateWithDuration block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

**I'm wandering what is the correct way to do "long" actions in response to user events.** For example, I have this slide to cancel block that animates itself off screen over 0.5 seconds. The `[self coreDataAction]` may take about 0.3 seconds itself.

I want to ensure that the action completes once the user sees the end of the animation ( I do not want the user to accidentally navigate to a different controller or close the app thinking that the action is done).

**Where should I put the `[self coreDataAction];` in this case?** Above the block, within the block or in the completion block?

```
//should I put it here?

 CGPoint slideToCancelCenter = slideToCancel.view.center;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.goToSleepButton.center = slideToCancelCenter;
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        CGPoint sliderCenter = slideToCancel.view.center;
        sliderCenter.y += slideToCancel.view.bounds.size.height;
        slideToCancel.view.center = sliderCenter;

//should I put it here?        
// [self coreDataAction];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
//should I put it here?
    } ];
```

Comment: The `[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];`is not needed, you've already set the duration. use that if you not using block based animation (see UIView class reference for the difference)

Comment: I don't think you should be making the user care about whether this "action" is done. Do the computation in the background and let the user move on to more important things than waiting for the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [self coreDataAction] executes on the main thread, I would say you should put it on the first line to ensure that the method is complete by the time the animation is done.

Comment: If any of the calls within the `coreDataAction` method are blocking calls the animation won't happen until after the `coreDataAction` finishes its execution. If this is the case, @AlexStone can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to kick it off asynchronously, but that will, at best, start the `coreDataAction` method's execution after the animation is queued.

Comment: from what i understood he doesn't want the animation to complete before coreDataAction. If you kick it off asynchronously, its possible for the animation to be complete and coreDataAction to still be working. Since the animation is only half a second, my thinking is that he just kick that off after coreDataAction.

Comment: There are additional concerns around core data action, as doing them from background threads may result in context merging required (two threads having their own scratchpads with different data). I'm not ready to do this kind of activity yet.

Comment: I ended up putting the call to core data above the animation. There are two animations - one in response to user sliding the slider, this is when the core data action is initiated. Once core data action completes, the slider is animated off screen.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to handle this might be to animate the view on-screen then start the `coreDataAction` in the completion handler. Once the `coreDataAction` method execution is complete you can call a method to animate the slide to cancel view off-screen.